# Ionic 4 with Tesseract offline getting "Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'importScripts' on 'WorkerGlobalScope'"

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4, tesseract.js

I am trying to use `Tesseract` in **offline** mode in my `Ionic 4` app. In order to do it I have based my code on what is explained in [this example](https://itnext.io/offline-ocr-with-tesseractjs-and-ionic-5054fc7eef86), although it is done with `Ionic 3` and what the Tesseract GitHub explains regarding [offline mode](https://github.com/naptha/tesseract.js#local-installation).

First, I have put the `Tesseract` files in the `src\assets\lib` directory as follows (the `tesseract-` prefix for the files has been added by me):

[image: Assets directory]

Next I created a service that basically creates a Tesseract offline mode instance as indicated in the above mentioned links:

```js
  const path = this.webview.convertFileSrc(this.file.applicationDirectory + 'www/assets/lib/');

  this.tesseract = await Tesseract.create({
    langPath: path + 'tesseract-', 
    corePath: path + 'tesseract-index.js',
    workerPath: path + 'tesseract-worker.js',
  });
```

Some notes on the code:

- `this.file` is a `File` from `'@ionic-native/file/ngx'`.
- The call to `convertFileSrc` is to avoid the `unable to load resource` error you get when trying to load the Javascript files directly.
- If i log with `this.file.listDir` the contents of `this.file.applicationDirectory + 'www/assets/lib/'` I can see the `Tesseract` files.

Now, when I deploy this to an `Android emulator (Pixel 2 API 28)` and try to call the function where this code is I get following error, as per the Chrome debugger:

[image: importScripts error]

FWIW, this is my environment:

```
Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)             : 4.12.0 (C:\Users\guillem.vicens\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v10.15.3\node_modules\ionic)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.1.2
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.13.6
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 7.2.4
   @angular/cli                  : 7.3.6
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 1.4.1

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : not installed
   Cordova Platforms     : android 8.0.0
   Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 3.1.2, (and 6 other plugins)

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk)
   NodeJS            : v10.15.3 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm               : 6.4.1
   OS                : Windows 10
```

What am I missing? What is the correct way to access the `assets` folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to solve my problem by using a non-calculated URL base.

I noticed that the `tesseract-tesseract-js` file was being loaded from the following URL:

```
http://localhost/assets/lib/tesseract-tesseract.js
```

But none of the others were loaded. This made me think that the problem was somehow related to the internal use in `Tesseract.js` of relative paths that collided with the webview security policies.

Changing my code to do following did the trick:

```js
  this.tesseract = await Tesseract.create({
    langPath: 'http://localhost/assets/lib/tesseract-', 
    corePath: 'http://localhost/assets/lib/tesseract-index.js',
    workerPath: 'http://localhost/assets/lib/tesseract-worker.js',
  });
```

I will have to test this on real mobile phones and on iOS, but this answers my original question.