# How to pass in Tesseract options for page segmentation?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic4, tesseract.js

I have been trying to figure out how to pass in tesseract options for page segmentation. I tried `tessedit_pageseg_mode: '1'`, But when I use it, the process stops at `recognizing text`. If I set it as number 1, then it finishes, but the mode is still default `SINGLE_BLOCK`.

I'm currently using Tesseract version: **1.0.19**. But I have also tried with **2.0.0-alpha.13**, but the result is same.

```
this.tesseract = Tesseract.create({
    workerPath: '../../assets/tesseract/worker.js',
    langPath: '../../assets/tesseract/trained-data',
    corePath: '../../assets/tesseract/core.js',
});
this.tesseract.recognize(this.image, {
    lang: 'eng',
    tessedit_pageseg_mode: '1'
})
.progress((p) => {
    console.log('progress', p);
    this.ocrResult = p.status + ', Progress: ' + Math.round(p.progress * 100) + '%';
})
.then((data) => {
    console.log(data.psm);
    this.ocrResult = data.text;
}).catch((err) => {
    console.error('Error occurred while recognizing text', err);
});
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

**Update:** 
I kind of figured out the issue, My previous code was written line this `window.Tesseract = Tesseract.create({...` but was directly using `Tesseract.recognize(..` this downloaded the worker, language and core file from the internet, but was not using the provided file from the path. For some reason the file download was getting aborted when I provided the option `tessedit_pageseg_mode: '1'`.

> Uncaught abort() at Error
>       at Na (https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/naptha/tesseract.js-core@0.1.0/index.js:36:26)

So, now I'm trying to make it use the local files by adding `file:///android_asset/www` ([as instructed in this blog](https://itnext.io/offline-ocr-with-tesseractjs-and-ionic-5054fc7eef86)) before in assets folder, but for some reason that's too is failing with this message

> Failed to load file:///android_asset/www/assets/plugins/tesseract/worker.js: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, https.`

Answer (score 1):

Try using localhost instead of relative path, like this:

```
  this.tesseract = Tesseract.create({
    workerPath: 'http://localhost/assets/tesseract/worker.js', 
    langPath: 'http://localhost/assets/tesseract/trained-data',
    corePath: 'http://localhost/assets/tesseract/core.js',
  });
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55667971/ionic-4-with-tesseract-offline-getting-uncaught-domexception-failed-to-execute)

Comment: Still getting uncaught error in importScripts method.

Comment: Does using localhost work on production environment?

Comment: Maybe not, but you can change localhost for your domain name: `ttp://mydomain.com/assets/tesseract/worker.js`, for example.